# What is the correct way to write product or sum in capital pi or capital sigma notation when you wish to exclude an index?

Tags: soft-question, terminology

I have a series of terms $\{t_n : t_n = a_n x_n\}$, and I want to talk about the product of each term except $t_j$.

Would any of these be an appropriate way to say that?  I like this:

$$\prod_{i \ne j} t_i$$

or maybe this

$$\prod_{i=1,i \ne j}^n t_i$$

Is it a normal thing to do, to put qualifiers on an index like that, or is there a better way to do it?

Or would it be better to make a subset, $\{b_n : a_n, n \ne j \}$ and use that:

$$\prod_{i=1}^n b_i$$

Comment: I think that either of the first two suggestions is fine (but in the case of the second, I would typeset $i \neq j$ *below* the line $i = 1$, rather than separating them with a comma); the third adds a complicating layer of notation that I don't think is necessary.

Comment: In addition to the fact that it is complicated (as Matt E pointed out), I do not think that the third suggestion is even correct.  It still denotes the product of the n numbers $b_1,\ldots,b_n$, which is not defined unless you specify the value of $b_j$.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It is normal to write

$$\prod_{\begin{matrix}i=1 \\ i \ne j \end{matrix}}^n t_i$$

but another good notation is

$$\prod_{t \in T \setminus \{t_j\}} t$$

(with $T = \{t_n : t_n = a_n x_n\}$, also note that it is only defined up to permutation)

Comment: Thanks, that's helpful.  What does "only defined up to permutation" mean?

Comment: When the first one defines $t_1 \cdot t_2 \cdot t_4$ but it's not clear which one of $\{ t_1 \cdot t_2 \cdot t_4,\;\; t_1 \cdot t_4 \cdot t_2,\;\; t_2 \cdot t_1 \cdot t_4,\;\; t_2 \cdot t_4 \cdot t_1,\;\; t_4 \cdot t_1 \cdot t_2,\;\; t_4 \cdot t_2 \cdot t_1 \}$ that the second defines - so unless they are all equal (i.e. multiplication is commutative) it is meaningless.

Comment: @muad: People write $\prod_{i=1}^{3} t_i$ for $t_1\cdot t_2\cdot t_3$ when multiplication is noncommutative? That's interesting. How do they write $t_3\cdot t_2\cdot t_1$?

Comment: @Rahul: Well they could just write t_(n-i) instead of t_i

Answer (score 1):

$\large{\text{Annex to Tsuyoshi Ito's Comment :}}$

I thought to provide some more detail. User Unkz defined: $b_n:= a_n, \forall \; n \neq j$. So $\color{red}{b_j}$ doesn't exist.

However, by definition of the Pi notation:
$\prod_{i=1}^n b_i := b_1b_2...b_{j-1}\color{red}{b_j}b_{j+1}...b_n$.
Since $\color{red}{b_j}$ doesn't exist but this product contains $\color{red}{b_j}$, therefore this product cannot exist either.